# How to read SQL Server Report history programatically?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

a SQL Reporting Services Question - for SQL Server 2008.

Given that SQL Server Reporting Services features a Scheduler which can be used to schedule the running of SQL Reports, does anyone know a way to programatically (via C#) read a report's history from the Report Server (and then perhaps retrieve the results of the report)?

So after some more digging, it looks like I need to generate a WSDL for the Report Server and then access information by using the ReportingService object - has anyone done this before (with 2008) and can provide some pointers?

Note: looks like (according to SQL 2008 books online) the WSDL address for SQL 2008 is:

```
http://server/reportserver/ReportService2005.asmx?wsdl
```

If I can get this working, I'll post an answer up with the basic steps to implementing it :)  It's a little confusing as the documentation is a mixture of SQL 2000 and SQL 2005 references!

Comment: +1 I wasn't even aware that this was even possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so I've actually figured out how to accomplish this seemigly impossible task.

Before I begin, let me just say that if you are working with SQL Server Reporting Services 2008 (SSRS 08) and *have* (i.e. you have no choice) to use something like Basic auth, you'll only find a world of hurt with the WCF based Service Stubs & IIS.  I'm going to blog about the configuration later.

The short answer is as follows:

- Connect (e.g. new ReportingService2005() or ReportingService2005SoapClient())

Note: It's easier to use the old (pre-WCF) ASMX service, but not impossible to use the new CF version.  The Authentication takes some configuring.  There are also some slight syntactic changes between versions.

- Find the report history you are looking for, e.g. ReportHistorySnapshot[] history = reportServer.ListReportHistory(@"/Reports/MyHandyReport");
- Get the HistoryID from whichever snapshot you want (returned from the ListHistoryReport)
- Now, use a ReportViewer to render the historic report, much like you would any other report, e.g.:

  ReportViewer rv = new ReportViewer();
  rv.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
  rv.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(@"http://localhost/reportserver");
  rv.ServerReport.ReportPath = @"/Reports/MyHandyReport";
  **rv.ServerReport.HistoryId = historyId;**
  //...snip
  byte[] bytes = rv.ServerReport.Render("Excel", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamids, out warnings);

Note: you can also use the second WCF Web Service (ReportExecution2005.asmx?wsdl) as well for Report Execution

Answer (score 1):

Well it has [soap](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/875447) and extensibility API, perhaps they can be used?

Comment: Yup, I was on that path actually :)  Doesn't look like it has changed between 2005 and 2008